# How to increase screen brightness past the limit on Mac

Tags: macos, screen-brightness

Max on my Macbook is 350 nits. New models are shipped with 400 or more.
I hoped Homebrew would help but brightness can only be set to 1, not 1.1 or
Hope there will be a way to manually overcome the limit.

Comment: IMHO, that sounds kind of like asking if you can turn up the speed on your old truck to make it beat a Ferrari.

Comment: Maybe try asking there? https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmmm. First thing I would try to learn is if the displays in the newer models are technically improved. I guess they are. The screens in the older models are probably not capable of providing 400 nits or more, or perhaps it would shorten their lifespan too much. I would only attempt to overcome that limit of 350 nits if I were absolutely sure that it wouldn't damage the screen.

Comment: @MarkSetchell . . . Sure you could. Just put a jet engine in/on the trunk. It will be faster than a Ferrari. But not very long, I guess... ;)